# Blender fails to load

Tags: startup-file

I've just tried to launch Blender. Nothing has changed except for a recent Windows upgrade. When I launch Blender it hangs then crashes at the launch screen. I cannot get any version (2.20, 2.78, 2.79, 2.80) to advance past the launch screen - like, at all. I've been using Blender since the day Steve Jobs died so I'm no noob.

- I've tried uninstalling and installing (many times)
- Installing previous versions
- Updating Windows and NVIDIA drivers
- Launching from the installer and from the .exe zip file

Any ideas would be great? No error messages apart from the Windows (Not Responding) before it just stops.

Help!

Comment: Please have look at the related questions and the right side.